# ¿Como detectar en Android si el dispositivo cambio el tipo de red wifi a datos y conocer el nombre de la red?

Tags: java, android

¿Como detectar en Android si el dispositivo cambio el tipo de red wifi a datos y conocer el nombre de la red ? es que necesito obtener esta información de la red para validar y ejecutar un método.

Answer (score 3):

Para detectar cambios en la red debes usar un [BroadcastReceiver](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html)

https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/connectivity-monitoring.html

Este es una clase ejemplo para detectar los cambios

```
public class NetworkStateReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {  
     if(intent.getExtras() != null) {
        NetworkInfo ni = (NetworkInfo) intent.getExtras().get(ConnectivityManager.EXTRA_NETWORK_INFO);
        if(ni != null && ni.getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED) {
            Log.i("Network", "Network connected : " + ni.getTypeName());
        } else if(intent.getBooleanExtra(ConnectivityManager.EXTRA_NO_CONNECTIVITY, Boolean.FALSE)) {
            Log.i("Network", "No existe conectividad!");
        }
   }
}
```

Tienes que registrar en tu AndroidManifest.xml el [BroadcastReceiver](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html), con el intent-filter `CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE` :

```
<receiver android:name=".NetworkStateReceiver">
   <intent-filter>
      <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE" />
   </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

y agregar el permiso:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

Comment: Y como uso esta clase y el metodo onReceive en otra clase para validar en esa clase y que alli dependiendo se ejecute o no otro un metodo como por ejemplo consultar una APIREST u otro.

Comment: @JDeveloper lo que puedes hacer es cuando quieres obtener los datos mediante APIREST comprueba el estado si hay wifi o datos, sin usar broadcast